# Recover from an interrupted 10.04 to 10.10 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I was almost through and downloading the packages and then the system froze up.

Upon reboot the message was "gnome-power-manager has configuration defaults not installed properly". How do I get my system back? I have only a blank screen with that message.

Comment: can you boot into recovery mode? i.e. when you get to the grub screen where you select which kernel, can you select the one which ends in recovery mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try issuing `sudo dpkg --configure -a` from a shell prompt.

If you can't boot normally, try selecting a recovery or earlier kernel from the grub screen as @Slipstream suggests, then opening a shell.